# SFML write to the console

Tags: c++, console, codeblocks, sfml

I'm writing a SFML project in c++, using Code::Blocks in Windows for my IDE. When I run the program through Code::Blocks, it opens a console window. Is there any simple way to write to that? I tried `std::cout<<"console output"<<std::endl;`, but that doesn't seem to do anything. I really just want this for debugging purposes, such as printing out an exception before the program closes. I haven't been able to find documentation on writing to a console. The only thing I found is writing to the main screen with `sf::Text`, which isn't really what I want.

Comment: Writing to standard output should result into printing the text message to the terminal. Maybe the execution flow never gets to the printing (or it gets to that few milliseconds before closing the terminal). Could you post a minimal, compilable example producing the problem?

Comment: Does your program open a console window when you run it outside of Code::Blocks? Sounds like a project configuration issue or Code::Blocks quirk?